# Книги и статьи по безопасности веб-приложений

Tags: php, безопасность, csrf, sql-injection, xss-атака

Занимаюсь разработкой на PHP. Хотел бы узнать все о безопасности веб-приложений.

Подскажите пожалуйста книги, статьи, вебинары и т.д. С чего лучше начать и чем закончить(чтобы идти как бы от простого к сложному)

Answer (score 0):

Какие книги? 21-й век на дворе.

1. [php.net](http://php.net)
2. [developer.mozilla.org](http://developer.mozilla.org)
3. [developers.google.com](http://developers.google.com)

Comment: Можно конечно весь php.net от корки до корки прочесть, но там информация обо всем PHP. Меня интересует только безопасность. Какие бывают уязвимости какие бывают виды атак и тд.

Comment: Про безопасность https://www.php.net/manual/ru/security.php и https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security я точно всё прочитал от корки до корки. И как видите живой. 

Comment: Хорошо, а где например php.net/manual/ru/security.php или developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security  про XSS и CSRF атаки? Там написаны какие банальные вещи про sql инъекции и Register_Globals про которые и так любой школьник знает

Comment: Я это к тому что, отправить читать мануалы это конечно очень умно, но хотелось бы чего то более конструктивного

Comment: Это оно и есть - кратенькое.  А так-то вообще надо спецификации читать.

Comment: Сначала поищите про основные вектора направления атак на веб-приложения, после этого будет проще понимать как они могут реализовываться в ваших частных случаях. XSS - один из них, изучайте дальше.